# Try to create a Fallback to APNS Push if socket.io connection fires disconnect event on node.js server

Tags: node.js, redis, socket.io, apple-push-notifications, publish-subscribe

is there an example available how to start pushing over apns if the earlier socket.io connection of a client interupts and the disconnect event fires on the node.js/socket.io server.

I do the following thing:

Connect client to websocket and subscribe a hash via pupSub channel to redis. Now when the client disconnects I want to push the channels he subscribed via APNS and GCM Server. So I want to send the updated data of the subscribed channels to the clients device.
I have appDeviceTokens available at the time when the client subscribes to redis.

Is there an Example enywhere how to resolve this.

regards Guido